# netty 4.0 input bytes decoding

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, netty, pipeline

i'm trying to implement a very simple socket server. I need to read some messages, split by a new line or any other delimiter.

According to this documentation: http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/string/StringDecoder.html and http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder.html

this code for the channel initializer

```
ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel> channelInitializer = new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
            @Override
            public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {

                ch.pipeline().addLast("frameDecoder", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
                ch.pipeline().addLast("stringDecoder", new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));

                // Encoder
                ch.pipeline().addLast("stringEncoder", new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
            }
         };
```

should do the trick.

but there are no suitable constructors for any of the decoders and encoders that would work with the supplied parameters. they expect some integer as first parameter and a Byte array. only the stringDecoder seems to be ok.

what am i missing here?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question and problem. Could you rephrase ?

Comment: In short: examples of usage taken from documentation don't work. That's the problem. Question is how to use it correctly

Answer (score 0):

The inline documentation for netty 4.0 is outdated at the moment -- but it's in an alpha/beta/development state.

The integer parameter is introduced to prevent unlimited buffer grow and specifies the maximum frame length.

So `new LineBasedFrameDecoder(4096))` is similar to `new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(Delimiters.lineDelimiter())`.